# Dynamic CSS Classes, REGEX and how to replace them

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently working on a project where class names are dynamically generated.
I need to style these to override some richface component for the jsf framework.

I have a bunch of css classes that have this format:

```
rf-edt-hdr-c_idt12  
rf-edt-hdr-c_idt13    
rf-edt-hdr-c_idt14
```

and so on and so forth.

It is nested pretty deeply in the html and I was wondering what would be the best way to handle this?
There are some nasty nested divs inside tables and I need to over ride its behaviour as I have no access to the components the developers used to do up some cleaner html.

Would it be a good idea to use jQuery and if so what plugin would be best?
I went down the css route using attribute value by selector by it's not behaving exactly how I want it to. (I think the nested tables and divs might have something to do with that).

It's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, use jQuery
2. Use the `starts-with` selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/. You can use `$('div[class^="rf-edt-hdr-c_idt"]')` to get your element.

Comment: Note however that this will only work if the class is the first class on the element. A `.filter()` solution would be more flexible.

Comment: True, though I think this answer is also just a push in the right direction for him.

Comment: Start with this, and check if it works. If it doesn't, come back here, and we'll try to make a more complex solution.

Comment: I'm trying to strip all the numerical values after the idt part in the class name. I'm not a developer and am not good at all at the programming part of css

Comment: `$('div[class^="rf-edt-hdr-c_idt"]').attr('class').substr("rf-edt-hdr-c_idt".length);` should give the ID.

Comment: Will this strip all values after the IDT and insert rf-edt-hdr-c_idt anywhere where there was a rf-edt-hdr-c_idt(.+?) class? thus allowing me to enter the css class as .rf-edt-hdr-c_idt?

Comment: Try it :) You should experiment, to arm yourself against other challenges. Learn from this, don't sit back and watch.